# Sentinel-2 SWIR (band 11) pansharpening

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sentinel-2, pansharpening

I am trying to downscale sentinel-2 SWIR band (11) from 20 m to 10 m in ArcGIS. The create Pan-sharpened Raster Dataset tool requires colored RGB image. I only want to downscale SWIR band because red green and blue bands are already at 10 m resolution. What is the possible workaround?

Comment: What are you using the downsampled SWIR band for?

Comment: @Aaron For MNDWI calculation

Answer (score 1):

You could run a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the 10m bands, take PCA 1 and then perform image fusion with the 20m band(s). Not sure about ArcGIS, but in GRASS GIS rather easily done (with [i.pca](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/i.pca.html) and the [i.fusion.hpf](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/i.fusion.hpf.html) addon). Also other fusion methods may work.

Example:

[image: Sentinel-2, original 20m land-water composite, Ratingen, Germany]
Sentinel-2, original 20m land-water composite, Ratingen, Germany

[image: Sentinel-2, pan-sharpened 10m land-water composite, Ratingen, Germany]
Sentinel-2, pan-sharpened 10m land-water composite, Ratingen, Germany

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the same task. I found useful information in these papers: https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/4/354, https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3900/2/7/345. Hopefully you'll find them helpful too.

I am trying to understand if the HPF can be directly applied to the SWIR B11 alone or if one has to create a composite image before applying this type of fusion and then obtain the band of interest in a second step. Possibly one of our more expert colleagues can help with this doubt.
I take the occasion to ask: for a quite new user do you suggest to just learn to use these already implemented tools like `i.fusion.hpf` or is it feasible to try to implement something more complex, like an ATWT? Would the difference in the result be worth the effort?